# JDBCTemplate - How to run an UPDATE statement with a Map<String, Object> as the parameter source?

Tags: java, parameters, sql-update, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

For an INSERT statement, one can do the following (db being an autowired JdbcTemplate):

```
var insert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(db)
    .withTableName("orders")
    .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("clientId", 25);

var key = insert.executeAndReturnKey(params);
```

I cannot find an equivalent update method that doesn't require passing each argument one by one.  I am making heavy use of reflection and generics in this and I simply cannot list each argument.  I would like to be able to do something like this :

```
db.update("UPDATE orders set clientId = ? WHERE id = ?", params, id);
```

Where params is a map containing the names and values of parameters to update and id is the ID of the row to affect.

Is this possible?

Comment: @Kayaman please post an answer and I shall accept it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JdbcTemplate` only uses `?` placeholders, but it has a closely related class [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) which is essentially the same class (it delegates to `JdbcTemplate`) but with named placeholders like `:clientId`.